# How can I store array that contains PFObjects in NSUserDefaults?

Tags: parse-platform, nsuserdefaults, nskeyedarchiver, pfobject, nskeyedunarchiver

Some PFObject contains PFFile(Image file) and some are not.When I am trying to store custom object in to user default using NSKeyedArchiver and NSKeyedUnarchiver, it won't work.

Help me how to store PFObjects array into UserDefault which contains PFFile type field.

Answer (score 0):

From [NSUserDefaults documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSUserDefaults_Class/index.html):

> A default object must be a property list, that is, an instance of (or for collections a combination of instances of): NSData, NSString, NSNumber, NSDate, NSArray, or NSDictionary. If you want to store any other type of object, you should typically archive it to create an instance of NSData.

So you can get your file's data by [getDataInBackgroundWithBlock](https://parse.com/docs/ios/api/Classes/PFFile.html#//api/name/getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:) and save it to NSUserDefaults:

```
    [file getDataInBackgroundWithBlock:^(NSData *data, NSError *error) {
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:data forKey:@"file"];
        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
    }];
```

There is also a library called [Parse-NSCoding](https://github.com/eladb/Parse-NSCoding) which adds NSCoding extension to Parse objects. It is not updated but you may check it out.

Comment: Yes. This solution is worked for individual PFFile but, I am looking for solution which stores full array of PFObject which contains so many PFFiles. Store one array in one UserDefault key.